# Is there a way to get element HOVER style while the element not in hover state?

Tags: javascript, dojo

```
<div id="test">

</div>

<style>
#test{
color: #000000;
}

#test:HOVER{
color: #ffffff;
}
</style>

var el = dojo.byId('test');

console.log(dojo.style(el, 'color') );

dojo.connect(el, 'onmouseenter', function(e){
var el = e.originalTarget;
console.log(dojo.style(el, 'color') );
});
```

I tested it in some browser and it didn't give always the white color, when the mouse entered. Sometime I got the default black color.

I would like to get this color value without hovering. Is there any way?

Comment: Your question is a little bit hard to understand. Can you please give us more information in terms of what you're trying to achieve? The browsers you're using and what you're expecting as the outcome.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: I started using cufon and raphael to generate nice fonts. It works fine while it's static without hover. When there is a hover, I have to redraw the text, but with the new hover font color, which in the CSS. I tried to get it, but IE7 and IE8 gives the unhovered color, because it changes the style pretty slow (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly you should be able to do this via `dojox.html.getStyleSheet`, iterating over the `CSSStyleRules` until you find the one you want and extracting the colour that way.

There isn't much in the docs for this, but the code is pretty well commented. See http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.6.1/dojo-release-1.6.1/dojox/html/styles.js